# Replace string between 2 words in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to replace string _allowduplicate here with Y or N

```
<Update AllowDuplicate='_allowduplicate'>
                <UserId>_patientid</UserId>
```

I dont want to use-

```
body.replace("_allowduplicate", "Y");
```

as I have to retain it for further execution

How can I do it with/without Regex?

Comment: If its XML you should use the XML DOM methods ...

Comment: Any clarifications on what you *want* to do?

Comment: So `body.replace("_allowduplicate", "Y");` is not working??

Comment: Its working, but I need to retain it. When I run body.replace("_allowduplicate", "N") second time, it will not find _allowduplicate

Comment: How do you want to retain it after replacing??? You can save it in another variable.

Comment: @stribizhev - I need to replace this string with/without regex, I tried soapBody.replace(/AllowDuplicate='.*'><PatientId>/, 'N') but it doesn't work

Comment: @Manwal No, I cannot. It comes from file content.

Comment: It doesn't matter what method you use to change `_allowduplicate` to `Y`, once you change it you won't be able to run something to replace `_allowduplicate` to `N` as `_allowduplicate` no longer exists.... you replaced it with `Y`... remember.  Think of what you're asking for "I want to **replace** string `_allowduplicate` here with `Y` or `N`"

Comment: @NewToJS I already mentioned I dont want to use- body.replace("_allowduplicate", "Y");

Comment: If there is a way to replace string between AllowDuplicate=' & <UserId>, let me know

Comment: @nickalchemist but the point is you want to replace something.... If you replace something and search for it after you won't find it because guess what... you replaced it!

Comment: So you don't want to replace `_allowduplicate` but you want to change the child content in the `<UserId>` tags? I think you need to edit your question and make it more clear for people to understand what you wish to achieve because at this moment in time it isn't making much sense.

Comment: @NewToJS - leave it, what I want to achieve is clearly mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Bearing in mind that you may change this parameter Y/N multiple times, I'm thinking it's best to convert your XML string into a proper object, so you can select the right tags/attributes to change.

jQuery has [parseXML()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/):

Example taken from their documentation:

```
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $title = $xml.find( "title" );

// Append "RSS Title" to #someElement
$( "#someElement" ).append( $title.text() );

// Change the title to "XML Title"
$title.text( "XML Title" );
```

With this, it would be very easy to replace the content of `AllowDuplicate`.

I don't work with XML often and have never used parseXML, but I would imagine your code would be something like this:

```
var xmlString = "<Update AllowDuplicate='_allowduplicate'><UserId>_patientid</UserId>",
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlString),
$xml = $(xmlDoc);

$xml.find('update').attr('AllowDuplicate', 'Y');
```

Comment: This will, but I am generating entire XML using string manipulation. Don't want to change logic for just for one field. Its a huge XML with more than 20 params. Can't redo complete logic

Comment: @nickalchemist - logic isn't logic if it's not working logically :) Using string manipulation to build/manipulate this XML document is obviously becoming difficult for you, and for developers willing to help you. $.parseXML was developed for this very reason. It's never too late to rewrite logic. Good luck regardless.